# Google maps dentro do segment Ionic 3?

Tags: google-maps, angular, ionic3

Gostaria de saber se é possível adicionar este mapa em uma aba do segment do ionic.

Eu até consegui usar o mapa perfeitamente como quero, porém gostaria de deixar ele apenas em uma aba do `segment`.

Quando coloco parece que ele fica fora do `segment` e ocupa todas as abas do `segment`.

## HTML

```
<div padding>
   <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="pet">
   <ion-segment-button value="inicio">
      Inicio
   </ion-segment-button>
   <ion-segment-button value="mapa">
      Mapa
   </ion-segment-button>
   </ion-segment>
</div>
<div [ngSwitch]="pet">
   <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'inicio'">
      <ion-list>
         <ion-item>
            <ion-label>De onde?</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="originPosition"></ion-input>
         </ion-item>
         <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Para onde?</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="destinationPosition"></ion-input>
         </ion-item>
         <div no-padding>
            <button ion-button (click)="calculateRoute()">Traçar rota</button>
         </div>
      </ion-list>
   </ion-list>
</div>
<div #map id="map"></div>
```

## HOME TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var google;

/**
 * https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  map: any;
  startPosition: any;
  originPosition: string;
  destinationPosition: string;

  constructor() { }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.initializeMap();
  }

  initializeMap() {
    this.startPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(-21.763409, -43.349034);

    const mapOptions = {
      zoom: 18,
      center: this.startPosition,
      disableDefaultUI: true
    }

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);

    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: this.startPosition,
      map: this.map,
    });
  }

  calculateRoute() {
    if (this.destinationPosition && this.originPosition) {
      const request = {
        // Pode ser uma coordenada (LatLng), uma string ou um lugar
        origin: this.originPosition,
        destination: this.destinationPosition,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
      };

      this.traceRoute(this.directionsService, this.directionsDisplay, request);
    }
  }

  traceRoute(service: any, display: any, request: any) {
    service.route(request, function (result, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {
        display.setDirections(result);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

[image: Mapa]

Comment: Só por curiosidade, qual as configurações css está utilizando nesse mapa?

Comment: para o mapa apenas : #map {
    height: 80%;
  }
.